# How do I set a default From email in CiviCRM to be used when assigning Activities?

Tags: email

A little help please
I am working on a civi system for an organisation that has volunteer supervisors  manning the phones and assigning "Activities" to other volunteers.
The email to the volunteer should come from a standard email address - Dutyofficer@...

However, the system defaults to the Volunteer supervisors email address and not the Dutyofficer one which is set up and used as default

Any ideas please﻿

Comment: Perhaps this related to this core bug https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25562/why-does-the-default-from-email-address-not-show-as-the-first-option-when-usin/25563#25563

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding Dutyofficer@... to each volunteer supervisor's record as an Other e-mail address perhaps and making that the Primary address for each - temporarily. That might work. Each volunteer may have to choose to send using that Dutyofficer@... address.

Comment: Ok it worked but... it needed the volunteers personal email address to be disabled,  It also means that I cannot see who initiated the activity as each is attributed to the Duty Officer

Comment: Hmm. Adding Dutyofficer@... as an Other email address and making it the volunteer's Primary e-mail address temporarily should have no effect on the actual personal (presumably Home) e-mail address for that volunteer user record. 

Where did you see the need to disable any email address?

Each volunteer has a user account in Civi and is signed in with that? 

What's the workflow/steps the volunteer takes to assign the activity?

Comment: Hey Pete, I tried the suggested method on my own site and Civi record, and it worked - the assignee received an e-mail with Assignment info from DutyOfficer@..... I did not have to disable my other [real] e-mail in my record. When trying the suggested method, are you making Dutyofficer@... an Other type e-mail for the user in the user record,and making that Other e-mail [temporarily] the Primary e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

In `Administer -> System Settings -> Outbound Email (SMTP/Sendmail)` there is a setting labelled "Allow mail from logged in contact". If you set this to no, then all assigned activity email will be sent from the default system-wide email address instead of the owner of the activity.

This setting should probably be off by default since email sent from your CiviCRM installation that claims to be from domain names not under your control (like Gmail or Yahoo) will be rejected as fraudulent by most email for providers (for failing SPF and DKIM checks).

Answer (score 0):

Each Volunteer acting as a Duty officer has a login into the wordpress web site which is linked to Civicrm.

I tried adding the Duty officer email address as primary for a test account and added an activty using that account and recieved an email from the personal email address.

The aim of the service is a Good Neighbour scheme - Volunteers will help local people with anything from gardening to hospital visits
The process
Each person who acts as a duty officer has editor access to the CiviCRM
Each Volunteer is a contact (Duty officers are also Volunteers)
A person requesting help is logged as a contact.

A telephone call is taken by the duty officer (VOIP system) this request is entered as an Activity - the duty officer assigns task against a volunteer with appropriate skills and times.  Civi then sends a confirmation email to the volunteer with details of the activity.

The From email address should be the duty officer - so that reponses are sent back to the logged email address and the private email adresses of volunteers are not shared.

The system also needs to track who is making changes for auditing etc.

Also many thanks Joe for taking the time to look at this

Comment: Seems like this is not an answer, but a continuation of the original question. Maybe editing the original question would be a better way to add this info so it doesn't get mixed up in the answers.