# Why does the default 'from' email address not show as the first option when using 'Send Email' Activity

Tags: email

This seems odd. If I add a second email address to the list of "from" emails at /civicrm/admin/options/from_email_address?reset=1 and set it to default, i expect it to be selected as the first option when using "Send an Email' but it continues to be the second in the list.

If i change the Order of the From emails so my default is first, it continues to show as the second when using "Send an Email' (though perhaps a clear of caches would fix it, but fundamentally something seems wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem in core and has been fixed by Jitendra - will add the PR when I can dig it out.

Comment: Just did the security upgrade to 5.3.1 and the logged-in user is showing up as the default FROM addresses in new contribution thank you emails instead of the address entered as the default. Can this be fixed (short of having the users email changed to what they want shown as a low-tech workaround!)??